Ranking objects in a vector
Given the following vector:
a <- c(1, 6, 6, 6, 11)

How do I output a corresponding vector of value ranks like the one below
1 2 2 2 5

If I use rank() function it produces 1 3 3 3 5

rank(x, na.last = TRUE, ties.method = c("average", "first", "last", "random", "max", "min"))

@user2974951 did you mean to say "min"?
